# firefox 53 for the Mac fails to load inline SVG images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, svg

I am working on a web app that makes use of SVG icons.
The icons are stored in a json file and loaded dynamically with jQuery.

This approach works fine in all browsers I have tested it on, i.e. Safari, Chrome, Opera, Roccat, Vivaldi, webkit, and Safari Technology Preview.

I haven't been able to test the page in a Windows browser, as my PC recently died on me, but it used to work fine, as well, at least with Edge.

However, Firefox 53 for the Mac ( and earlier versions too) refuses to load these images. In the console I get this error message: "Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed."

I am not sure what is invalid about my URIs, as they seem to be ok for other browsers.

You can check out this issue for yourself at http://www.immersive-tours.ch . Simply load the page first with something other than Firefox and then with Firefox.

Below you see one of the icons being loaded from the json file.

```js
"search": "<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0' y='0' width='48' height='48' viewBox='0, 0, 48, 48'> <g id='Layer_1' transform='translate(-150.523, -113.593)'> <g id='search.svg'> <g> <g> <path d='M171.376,124.593 C176.736,124.593 181.081,128.938 181.081,134.298 C181.03,136.306 180.488,138.26 179.293,139.898 L186.629,147.23 C187.349,147.95 187.699,149.453 186.979,150.174 C186.259,150.894 184.896,150.613 184.176,149.893 L176.629,142.449 C175.087,143.49 173.225,143.984 171.376,144.003 C166.017,144.003 161.672,139.658 161.672,134.298 C161.672,128.938 166.017,124.593 171.376,124.593 z M171.304,127.625 C167.714,127.625 164.804,130.535 164.804,134.125 C164.804,137.715 167.714,140.625 171.304,140.625 C174.893,140.625 177.804,137.715 177.804,134.125 C177.804,130.535 174.893,127.625 171.304,127.625 z' fill='#FFFFFF'/> <path d='M171.376,124.593 C176.736,124.593 181.081,128.938 181.081,134.298 C181.03,136.306 180.488,138.26 179.293,139.898 L186.629,147.23 C187.349,147.95 187.699,149.453 186.979,150.174 C186.259,150.894 184.896,150.613 184.176,149.893 L176.629,142.449 C175.087,143.49 173.225,143.984 171.376,144.003 C166.017,144.003 161.672,139.658 161.672,134.298 C161.672,128.938 166.017,124.593 171.376,124.593 z M171.376,125.593 C166.569,125.593 162.672,129.491 162.672,134.298 C162.672,139.106 166.569,143.003 171.366,143.003 C173.102,142.985 174.752,142.51 176.069,141.62 L176.748,141.162 L177.331,141.737 L184.883,149.186 C185.304,149.607 186.033,149.705 186.272,149.466 C186.495,149.243 186.358,148.374 185.922,147.937 L178.586,140.605 L177.98,139.999 L178.485,139.308 C179.502,137.916 180.033,136.194 180.081,134.298 C180.081,129.491 176.184,125.593 171.376,125.593 z M171.304,126.625 C175.446,126.625 178.804,129.983 178.804,134.125 C178.804,138.267 175.446,141.625 171.304,141.625 C167.162,141.625 163.804,138.267 163.804,134.125 C163.804,129.983 167.161,126.625 171.303,126.625 L171.304,126.625 z M171.304,127.625 L171.303,127.625 C167.714,127.625 164.804,130.535 164.804,134.125 C164.804,137.715 167.714,140.625 171.304,140.625 C174.893,140.625 177.804,137.715 177.804,134.125 C177.804,130.535 174.893,127.625 171.304,127.625 z' fill='#FFFFFF' fill-opacity='0.01'/> </g> </g> </g> </g> </svg> ",
```

This and other icons are loaded with this function:

```js
function loadIcons() {
 $.getJSON("/sys/icons/toursListing/listing.json", getIcons);
 function getIcons(icons) {
  $("#logo").attr("src", icons["logo"])
  $("#designImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['design']);
  $("#suggestionsImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['suggestions']);
  $("#swissToursMapImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['toursMap']);
  $("#searchImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['search']);
  $("#settingsImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['settings']);
  $("#onArrivalImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['onArrival']);
  $("#myToursImg").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['myTours']);
  $("#showCp img").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['showCp']);
  $("#hideCp img").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons['hideCp']);
  $("#closeSuggestionsIcon").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["closeButton"]);
  $("#hideToursMap img").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["hideTab"]);
  $("#hideSearchBtn").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["hideTab"]);
  $("#closeDesignIcon").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["closeButton"]);
  $("#liveScapes").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["liveScapes"]) 
  $("#contact img").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["contact"]);
  $(".arrow").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8, " + icons["rightArrow"]);
 };
}
```

And that's all there is tit.

Comment: Thats kind of off topic but on the mobile version of your site the arrow to hide the bottom bar could be on the left side 90 degree changed and the animation to hide to the right - it looks like a back to the top Button but isnt - Sorry for the UX/UI recommendation but that hurt me right now.

Comment: Put it in your HTML source source directly. It looks like a path problem, "Invalid URI":

Comment: @Felix Häberle: good point, thank you. I'll make the control panel disappear horizontally instead of vertically, but that icon has to stay there, on the right. Positioning those icons it's not an easy job, changes would break the spatial consistency across pages.

Comment: @Robert: "It contains a # character..."  Not quite sure what you mean. The SVG data contains a color rule (fill='#FFFFFF') but it's not in the URL, it's part of the SVG code.

Comment: Nope, the only URL required is the one to the json file, in my case "/sys/icons/toursListing/listing.json"

Comment: Pure SVG code, as in the first code snippet.

Comment: I don't see how that SVG is invalid. It's perfectly valid code, you can copy and paste it in any browser and it will display correctly. The issue here is why FIREFOX and Firefox ONLY can't load it, while every other browser on any platform can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters are reserved in URIs and must be encoded per [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). The # character is one such character. Firefox rightly reports your URI as invalid.

If other browsers don't report this as an error they are not correctly implementing the requirements of rfc3986.

It's fairly simple to call [encodeURI(URI)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to convert your SVG string.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you for your explanation. BTW, there is an alternative to URI encoding: declare colors using rgb(...) or rgba(...) instead of #xxxxxx. Works just as well, and may be a bit more efficient, at least in my case.